# Group generation algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I'm making a group generator, where students submit preferences to whom they would like to be in a group with: 1 is best, 2 is second best and so on. I then have a method where how good two students would be matched is calculated, this is based on preferences and how often you've been together with that person in the past. It just returns an integer. If the number is low then you're well matched, if it's high, not so much.

A group size is passed in and the groups are made.

The thing I don't know how to go about is to use that method to make groups that make sure the students are matched as good as possible in relation to the number. Are there any pre-existing algorithms for this?

BTW the surplus of students is just distributed across the first couple of groups.

Comment: Maximum-weight matching.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ Thank you, it definitely looks like something I can use, although I try to **minimize** the value between students, but that shouldn't be a problem. But could you please elaborate? How does my situation fit in with the algorithm?

Comment: what do you want to optimize? I mean what are the characteristics of best combination? students' preferences? or the "goodness" of the students in the groups?

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ The relational value between all students in a group should be as small as possible.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ Let's call the sum of the relational value between all students in a group the group value. For example say Jack, Jason and Joe is in a group, then this group's group value would be the sum of the relational value between Jack and Jason, Jack and Joe and Jason and Joe. Here's a [sketch](https://www.dropbox.com/s/86hxbw6kisxqo37/Relational%20value%20sketch.png?dl=0) Overall I want the sum of the group values of all groups to be as small as possible.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ You could place all students in a class in a circle, then draw a line between all of them so you could take any 2 students and there would be a line between them, that line would have a value, that is the relational value between those 2 students.

Comment: Then what would the preferences of the student mean? You dont want to optimize the priorities in the list of each student?

Comment: And also, do you have a restriction on the size of the groups? minimum? maximum? can groups be with different sizes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134260/discussion-between-martin-and-a).

Answer (score 2):

Simulated annealing works well for these types of optimisation problems. The energy is the sum of the student's ranks for every other student in the group, and you want to minimise it, with the restraint that all groups are equal (plus a fudge for surplus students).

You have to fiddle with the program to get the temperature and cooling schedule right. But if you don't insist on a perfect result, you should pretty easily get a good result.

Answer (score 2):

you could brute force generate all the "good groups" (groups that score well).

Then use linear integer programming where you have a variable Gi that is 1 or 0, which means the ith Group G either exists or not.

The objective function to maximise is the Sum of the Gi variables. The constraints are that Gi + Gj = 0 for any two groups Gi and Gj if the two groups both contain the same student.

Edit: i've found a way to do this exactly with linear integer programming.

`Maximize sum(Cij * Xij)` (cost of pairing students i and j multiplied by 1 or 0 based on if they are paired or not, `Xij = 1 or 0`)

constraint for each group, `Gk = SUM(Gk.ij) == group size`

constraint that `SUM(Gk.ij) over all k & j == 1` (each student is in one group)